# SQL Server Temporal Tables - How do I enter a row that isn't "now"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temporal-tables

I'm working on a system that will periodically process messages from an external source and store the result in our database.  In particular, it receives messages like "Patient X moved to Location Y at 09:45 AM, 10/22/2018..."

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use SQL Server's Temporal Tables to create a historical trail of "where the patient has been", so that I can query where they were at a specific point in time.

```
-- ============================================================
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Patients] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Patients] PRIMARY KEY([Id]),

    -- Data...
);

-- ============================================================
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Locations] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Locations] PRIMARY KEY([Id]),

    -- Data...
);

-- ============================================================
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PatientLocations] (
    [PatientId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_PatientLocations] PRIMARY KEY([PatientId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PatientLocations_PatientId] FOREIGN KEY([PatientId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Patients] ([Id]),

    [LocationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PatientLocations_LocationId] FOREIGN KEY([LocationId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Locations] ([Id]),

    [DateStartedUtc] datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [DateEndedUtc] datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([DateStartedUtc],[DateEndedUtc])
)
WITH ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON ( HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[PatientLocations_History] ) );
```

The problem is that [DateStartedUtc] can only be populated with the current system time, which isn't necessarily the time when the patient's location changed.

**My specific question is:**
 - Is there a good way to input new data into a Temporal Table but tag it with specific start dates? (Does [DateStartedUtc] have to be "GENERATED"?)
 - If not, are there other best practices for storing an queryable history table?

**Edited to add:**
 - Aaron reminded me in the comments to mention turning System Versioning OFF and ON again.  One potential solution I researched would be to turn System Versioning off, insert a new row into dbo.PatientLocations or dbo.PatientLocations_History, and turn System Versioning back on (all within a transaction).  I don't think that's a good solution for regular updates to the table (and it would require me to manually maintain the start and end dates), but I'm open to being convinced.

**Additional Updates**

To add some more context, my initial solution (before I discovered Temporal Tables) was to maintain a single history table with a trigger:

```
-- ============================================================
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Patients] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Patients] PRIMARY KEY([Id]),

    -- Data...
);

-- ============================================================
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Locations] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Locations] PRIMARY KEY([Id]),

    -- Data...
);

-- ============================================================
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PatientLocations] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_PatientLocations] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),

    [PatientId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PatientLocations_PatientId] FOREIGN KEY([PatientId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Patients] ([Id]),

    [LocationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PatientLocations_LocationId] FOREIGN KEY([LocationId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Locations] ([Id]),

    -- Timestamps
    [LocationStartedAtDateOffset] [datetimeoffset] NOT NULL,
    [_LocationCompletedAtDateOffset] [datetimeoffset] NULL,
);
GO

-- ================================================================================
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_PatientLocations_LocationCompletedAtDateOffset]
ON [dbo].[PatientLocations]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    WITH
    -- ========================================
    [ModifiedPatientIds] AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT [PatientId]
        FROM (
            SELECT [PatientId] FROM inserted
            UNION SELECT [PatientId] FROM deleted
        ) p
    ),
    -- ========================================
    [PList] AS (
        SELECT
            p.[Id],
            p.[PatientId],
            p.[LocationStartedAtDateOffset],
            LEAD(p.[LocationStartedAtDateOffset], 1)
                OVER(PARTITION BY p.[PatientId] ORDER BY p.[LocationStartedAtDateOffset])
                AS [LocationCompletedAtDateOffset]
        FROM [dbo].[PatientLocations] p
        JOIN [ModifiedPatientIds] mp ON p.[PatientId] = mp.[PatientId]
    )
    -- ========================================
    UPDATE p SET
        p.[_LocationCompletedAtDateOffset] = pl.[LocationCompletedAtDateOffset]
    FROM [dbo].[PatientLocations] p
    JOIN [PList] pl ON p.[Id] = pl.[Id]
END;
GO
```

I initially moved away from this solution, since triggers generally perform badly.

I *thought* Temporal Tables would solve my problem elegantly, but as the comments mention, they are really only designed for system versioning, not user-defined versioning.

**So my modified question is:**
 - What is the best way to store and maintain user-defined history in a database?
 - Is there a better solution than using triggers?  Or is there a more efficient way to use triggers?

Comment: This is **system versioning** only. You need to turn off system versioning, modify the row in the history table, then turn it back on. What you are looking for is called **application versioning** but that has not yet been implemented in SQL Server.

Comment: Right!  Thanks!  I did forgot to mention the possibility of turning system versioning off and on again.  I know that's the best way to backfill a temporal table, but I assume that defeats half the purpose of a temporal table if we have to update it manually.

Comment: I'll research "application versioning" to see if there are best practices out there.

Comment: It defeats the purpose of application versioning. It doesn't defeat the purpose of system versioning, which is actually to make it impossible to introduce discrepancies from reality. You have to turn off system versioning to allow those discrepancies. I think it's working as designed. :-)

Comment: Yes, turning it off and back on again, while a viable solution for most problems in *The IT Crowd*, is not practical as an ongoing process for versioning individual rows (it takes metadata locks, so it's not exactly scalable to begin with). Unfortunately you'll have to miss out on the nice new syntax for historical querying (`AS OF`, `BETWEEN`) but you can write these as conventional queries as well, and the current rows are easily retrieved with a view.

Comment: If a system versioning table isn't going to work, would you recommend maintaining a home brewed "application versioning" using triggers?  Or let the code calculate the correct start and end dates manually before inserting rows?  I'm willing to drop Temporal Tables as a solution, but I'm not sure which solution to use instead.

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure the logic is centralized, and not spread out across individual applications if they don't actually have to explicitly deal with history. That may mean an updatable view (`INSTEAD OF` triggers), or stored procedures, or just a shared library if all your app code will be written for the same platform. If you're already using stored procedures for data access, those are a natural fit, otherwise I'd probably go with an updatable view. Not as frictionless as a built-in history feature, but still transparent for clients, and storage details are kept on the DB.